# NGINX pass image requests to dynamic server

Tags: nginx

NGINX in front of NodeJS server.  NodeJS applications generate dynamic content (attached files such as png) and then call Twilio SMS API (MMS msg) which is provided a URL to the attachment.  How to pass these URL requests through to the NodeJS server as they are not static content in NGINX.

Example:  png image generated by NodeJS, and must be immediately accessible to Twilio API via URL that comes in through NGINX in front of NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

If nodejs generates URLs for PNG and these URLs are similar to each other at least part of the path, you can insert them in nginx location with regexp. But it should go before location, which handles regular PNGs.

For example if your static pngs are in location

```
...

location ~ ^/.+\.(png|jpg|txt|css|js|ttf)$ {
  root /var/www/html;
}
...
```

and your nodejs generates pngs on path like "/twilio/abcabc/123.png". Than you can insert this location before location with static:

```
...

location ~ ^/twilio/.+\.png$ {
  proxy_pass http://nodejs;
}

location ~ ^/.+\.(png|jpg|txt|css|js|ttf)$ {
  root /var/www/html;
}

...
```

In [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) described order how request matchin location:
"Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file."